# Responsive container almost full of buttons

Tags: css

Is there a way to justify buttons inside a division.
The buttons have different sizes.

[image]

I tried with flexbox but I hope there is another way.
This is the solution with flexbox that I want to change because it's an ugly hack:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    flex-grow: 999999999999;
}
.container button {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/hfme3qw0/

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/o56rpeam/

The problem I'm facing is more clear in the last fiddle where the buttons on the last row have a different size than those above. Try to resize the container...

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide a simple mock up with jsfiddle, please?

Comment: maybe its me, but I didn't understand "justify inside a division" means?

Comment: @Corbuk sure, I've updated the question and there is a jsfiddle now.

Comment: @Corbuk justify like the text (on both left and right).

Comment: the current flexbox solution has issues?

Comment: Could you please explain further the result you want, also a little confused as to what your problem is, thanks.

Comment: If you try to resize the container in this new jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o56rpeam/ you can see the buttons on the last row have a different size than the others above. That is the main problem I'd like to fix, thank you.

Comment: okay so what if you have a long text inside some buttons?

Comment: @kukkuz I want buttons to behave pretty much like "text-align: justify". My solution kind of works but when the buttons have the same size you can see there is something wrong with the last row.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but afaik you already have a *hacky* but more-or-less *okay* solution